# how can i export radgridview to PDf in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, telerik

i am using `RadGridView` to showing detail now I want to Export this data to PDF format. I am working on `VB.net` . I have imported

`Telerik.WinControls.UI`, `Telerik.WinControls.UI.Export`,    `Telerik.WinControls.UI.Export.ExportToExcelML`, `Telerik.WinControls.Data`

namespaces and I am using 
 Dim pdfExporter As 
`New Telerik.WinControls.Export.GridViewPdfExport(Me.grdTitles)`

but it is not supporting

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be good Telerik documentation on using the PDF in VB and C#, there seems to be 2 options to export to PDF.

- The ***GridViewPdfExport*** object utilizes the powerful RadPdfProcessing
  library and exports RadGridView`s data natively to the PDF format.
  (Recommended)
- The ***ExportToPdf*** object on the other hand first renders RadGridView as
  an XHTML table and the export process will convert that table to a PDF document. That said, Export to PDF supports all of the ExportToHTML settings, but it also adds some PDF specific ones.

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-exporting-data-export-to-pdf.html

The GridViewPdfExport functionality is located in the TelerikExport.dll assembly. You need to include the following namespace in order to access the types contained in TelerikExport:

- Telerik.WinControls.Export

`Dim pdfExporter As New Telerik.WinControls.Export.GridViewPdfExport(Me.RadGridView1)`

RunExport: Runs synchronously.

```
Dim fileName As String = "c:\ExportedData.pdf"   
pdfExporter.RunExport(fileName)
```

or
RunExportAsync: Runs on a thread different than the UI thread.

```
Dim fileNameAsync As String = "c:\ExportedDataAsync.pdf"
pdfExporter.RunExportAsync(fileNameAsync)
```